# Concatenate two VLOOKUP arrays

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas, string-concatenation

I have two columns as arrays:
Column (A) `= ArrayFormula(ifna(VLOOKUP(F2:F,Auditors!A:B,2,0)))`
Column (B) `= ArrayFormula(ifna(VLOOKUP(G2:G,Supervisor!A:B,2,0)))`

The only way is to concatenate them and copy paste to the end of column, but I need help to concatenate them as a new array separated by `,`:
`A,B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need concatenation like this?

```
=ArrayFormula(ifna(VLOOKUP(F2:F,Auditors!A:B,2,0) & ", " & VLOOKUP(G2:G,Supervisor!A:B,2,0)))
```